# Unable to deploy contract to rinkeby test network using truffle

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain, truffle, contract-deployment

These are the steps I took in order to deploy my contracts to rinkeby network:

1. Created a .rinkeby folder.
2. Downloaded genesis json for rinkeby from [here](https://www.rinkeby.io/rinkeby.json)
3. Ran this command :

   geth --datadir=$HOME/.rinkeby --light init rinkeby.json
4. Ran this command :

   geth --networkid=4 --datadir=$HOME/.rinkeby --syncmode=light --bootnodes=enode://a24ac7c5484ef4ed0c5eb2d36620ba4e4aa13b8c84684e1b4aab0cebea2ae45cb4d375b77eab56516d34bfbd3c1a833fc51296ff084b770b94fb9028c4d25ccf@52.169.42.101:30303?discport=30304 --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*"
5. After I had geth connected to the network, I used truffle with the following code & command to deploy the contract:

Code:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    rinkeby: {
      network_id: 4,
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 8545,
      gas: 4000000
    },
  },
  rpc: {
    // Use the default host and port when not using rinkeby
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8080,
  },
};
```

Command:

```
truffle compile; truffle migrate --network rinkeby
```

This is the error I am getting :

```
Using network 'rinkeby'.

/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:23538
        throw new Error("Expected parameter '" + key + "' not passed to function.");
        ^

Error: Expected parameter 'from' not passed to function.
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:23538:15
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.options (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:23536:19)
    at Object.run (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:66868:12)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:88946:23
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:67033:9
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:66861:7
    at done (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:155469:5)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:155526:11
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:5)
```

What is incorrect in the process that I followed? I cant understand why this error is coming and how to remove it.

Comment: did you compiled the contract with `truffle compile`?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the step that I missed in my question.

Comment: Does your account have enough funds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was in the truffle.js file.

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    rinkeby: {
      network_id: 4,
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 8545,
      gas: 4000000,
      from: <your account address>
    },
  },
  rpc: {
    // Use the default host and port when not using rinkeby
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8080,
  },
};
```

Just needed to add a `from: <account address>` into rinkeby's config information.

Answer (score 0):

I've had my fair share of hardship with truffle config. I've made my on little lib for deployment using ethers.js. Hopefully this can be of help to someone in the future:

```
const etherlime = require('etherlime');

const ICOTokenContract = require('./build/contracts/ICOToken.json');

const randomAddress = '0xda8a06f1c910cab18ad187be1faa2b8606c2ec86';

const defaultConfigs = {
    gasPrice: 20000000000,
    gasLimit: 4700000
}

const deployer = new etherlime.InfuraPrivateKeyDeployer('Your Privste KEY', 'ropsten', 'Your infura API key', defaultConfigs);

const runICODeployment = async () => {
    const contractWrapper = await deployer.deploy(ICOTokenContract);
    const transferTransaction = await contractWrapper.contract.transferOwnership(randomAddress);
    const result = await contractWrapper.verboseWaitForTransaction(transferTransaction.hash, 'Transfer Ownership');
}
runICODeployment()
```

Place this in a js file and run it via node